# Linq query to fill a list in a nested class receiving an error

Tags: c#, linq

I'm a newbie both in C#, Linq and .Netcore what I'm trying to do is translate the following query in sql to linq

```
SELECT
p.policyId,
p.insuranceId,
p.policyType,
p.coverageType,
p.price,
us.FirebaseUID
FROM Policies p
JOIN Users us ON p.userId = us.FirebaseUID
```

My policy is a nested class that is inside the parent class ExampleRes I followed this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11909166/linq-query-to-fill-complex-model) answer in order to populate the policy list but I'm getting **this error**:

```
Error CS1061: 'ExampleRes.PoliciesInfo' does not contain a definition for 'ToList' and no extension method 'ToList' accepting a first argument of type 'ExampleRes.PoliciesInfo' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

This is the **query** I'm using

```
public List<ExampleRes> GetUserInfo(string fuid)
    {

        var policies = (from pol in _context.Policy
                        join us in _context.User
                        on pol.userId equals us.FirebaseUID
                        select new ExampleRes
                        {
                            userId = us.userId,
                            fuid = us.FirebaseUID,
                            policy = (new ExampleRes.PoliciesInfo
                            {
                                policyId = pol.policyId,
                                policyType = pol.policyType,
                                policyPrice = pol.price,
                                coverageType = pol.coverageType
                            }).toList()
                        }).toList();

        return policies;
    }
```

And this is the **ExampleRes class**

```
public class ExampleRes
{
    public ExampleRes()
    {
    }

    // User info
    public int userId { get; set;}
    public string fuid { get; set; }
    public List<PoliciesInfo> policy { get; set; }

    // Policies info
    public class PoliciesInfo{

        public int policyId { get; set; }
        public int policyType { get; set; }
        public int coverageType { get; set; }
        public int policyPrice { get; set; }

    }

}
```

Comment: is the `toList()` (small `t`) a typo?

Comment: should be `ToList()` with capital `T` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query should be like this:

```
var policies = (from pol in _context.Policy
                join us in _context.User
                on pol.userId equals us.FirebaseUID
                select new ExampleRes
                {
                    userId = us.userId,
                    fuid = us.FirebaseUID,
                    policy = new List<ExampleRes.PoliciesInfo> {
                        new ExampleRes.PoliciesInfo
                        {
                             policyId = pol.policyId,
                             policyType = pol.policyType,
                             policyPrice = pol.price,
                             coverageType = pol.coverageType
                        }
                    }
                }).ToList();
```

**UPDATED:**

I misunderstand the question, should be like this. But I believed that there should be a better solution.

```
var policies = (from us in _context.User
                select new ExampleRes
                {
                    userId = us.userId,
                    fuid = us.FirebaseUID,
                    policy = (
                        from pol in _context.Policy
                        where pol.userId == us.FirebaseUID
                        select new ExampleRes.PoliciesInfo
                        {
                            policyId = pol.policyId,
                            policyType = pol.policyType,
                            policyPrice = pol.price,
                            coverageType = pol.coverageType
                        }
                    ).ToList()
                }).Where(u => u.policy.Count > 0).ToList();
```

**UPDATED AGAIN**

Combining both linq function queries with non-functional queries is a bad practice, thanks @Ilan Keshet. Here is my modified solution:

```
var policies = (from pol in _context.Policy
                group pol by pol.userId into uid
                where uid.Count() > 0
                join us in _context.User
                on uid.Key equals us.FirebaseUID
                select new ExampleRes
                {
                    userId = us.userId,
                    fuid = us.FirebaseUID,
                    policy = (from pol in _context.Policy
                              where pol.userId == uid.Key
                              select new ExampleRes.PoliciesInfo
                              {
                                  policyId = pol.policyId,
                                  policyType = pol.policyType,
                                  policyPrice = pol.price,
                                  coverageType = pol.coverageType
                              }).ToList()
                }).ToList();
```

Comment: Works great but I'm repeating the userId "n" times, how can I just populate my policy to work like an array? in order not to repeat the userId and fuid?. Sorry for any inconvenience

Comment: @BillyTarak Do you mean that you want to get an ExampleRes object, which has an array of policy in its property?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I tried to do, I want to have a response where I receive the user information and an key policy which is an array that has "n" policies for that specified user. I thought that using List will make the trick @NeoChoi

Comment: Combining both linq function queries with non-functional queries seems quite bad practice

Comment: @IlanKeshet I'm new to linq and the whole netcore ecosystem so if you have any advice could be helpful

Comment: My advice -- only stick with Linq function calls. IE all the lower case query operations like 'select', 'from'...  Don't use them. No idea why C# thought it was a good idea to put those in.  Function queries are just so much more readable

Comment: Im getting an error in the last line Error CS0019: Operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'method group' and 'int' @NeoChoi -> Nevermind, it works like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: @IlanKeshet Thanks for your advice, it is really a bad practice, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for [Nested query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9334919/linq-nested-query)

Try something like this:

```
var policies = (from pol in _context.Policy
                        join us in _context.User
                        on pol.userId equals us.FirebaseUID into policies
                        select new ExampleRes
                        {
                            userId = us.userId,
                            fuid = us.FirebaseUID,
                            policy = (from p in policies
                                      select new ExampleRes.PoliciesInfo
                            {
                                policyId = p.policyId,
                                policyType = p.policyType,
                                policyPrice = p.price,
                                coverageType = p.coverageType
                            }).ToList()
                        }).ToList();
```

Or

```
var policies = (from us in _context.User
                        select new ExampleRes
                        {
                            userId = us.userId,
                            fuid = us.FirebaseUID,
                            policy = _context.Policy
                                             .Where(pol=>pol.userId == us.FirebaseUID)
                                             .Select(new ExampleRes.PoliciesInfo
                                             {
                                                 policyId = pol.policyId,
                                                 policyType = pol.policyType,
                                                 policyPrice = pol.price,
                                                 coverageType = pol.coverageType
                                             }).ToList()
                        }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant call `ToList()` on your `ExampleRes.PoliciesInfo` its not an [Enumerable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable(v=vs.110).aspx) of any sort

```
policy = (new ExampleRes.PoliciesInfo
            {
                policyId = pol.policyId,
                policyType = pol.policyType,
                policyPrice = pol.price,
                coverageType = pol.coverageType
             }).toList()  // <== doesn't make sense
```

in short you need to create a new List with your instantiated class as the element

```
new List<blah> { new blah() {...} }
```

[Enumerable.ToList Method (IEnumerable)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Creates a List from an IEnumerable.

Answer (score 0):

First the `toList()` (small `t`) will result in a compile time error. Change that to `ToList()` (capital `T`).

Secondly, the `policy` property is a `List<PoliciesInfo>` (list of policiesinfo), and you are setting it wrongly.

What you should do instead is this:

```
policy = new List<Examples.PoliciesInfo> {                 
             new Examples.PoliciesInfo {
                   policyId = pol.policyId,
                   policyType = pol.policyType,
                   policyPrice = pol.price,
                   coverageType = pol.coverageType
             }
             // you can create more Examples.PoliciesInfo here, just seperate them with comma
         }.ToList()
```

This will fix.

Comment: Works great but I'm repeating the userId "n" times, how can I just populate my policy to work like an array? in order not to repeat the userId and fuid?. Sorry for any inconvenience @jmesolomon

Comment: @BillyTarak if you have another question, you should open another question thread for that.